# How to partition my 'timeconsume' feature as per pandas datetimeindex

Tags: pandas, datetime, partitioning

I have a time-based feature in my pandas 5 min interval data frame, so it looks something like

```
      dataDate               TimeconinSec

     2020-11-11 22:25:00     302
     2020-11-11 23:25:00     605
     2020-11-12 00:25:00     302
```

few times this feature may have value beyond 5 mins( 300sec), so I want it to be like the following output, going back on time and distribute the time feature

```
    dataDate               TimeconinSec

     2020-11-11 22:20:00     300
     2020-11-11 22:25:00     002
     2020-11-11 23:15:00     300
     2020-11-11 23:20:00     300
     2020-11-11 23:25:00     005
     2020-11-12 00:20:00     300 
     2020-11-12 00:25:00     002
```

I have tried different pandas date range functions, but how can I partition my time-based features across the intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s first convert everything to proper timestamps, and compute the beginning and end of every interval:

```
>>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dataDate'])
>>> df['since'] = (df['date'] - df['TimeconinSec'].astype('timedelta64[s]')).dt.floor(freq='300s')
>>> df['until'] = df['since'] + df['TimeconinSec'].astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

Then we can use `pd.date_range` to generate all the proper intermediate interval bounds:

```
>>> bounds = df.apply(lambda s: [*pd.date_range(s['since'], s['until'], freq='300s'), s['until']], axis='columns')
>>> bounds
0    [2020-11-11 22:15:00, 2020-11-11 22:20:00, 202...
1    [2020-11-11 23:10:00, 2020-11-11 23:15:00, 202...
2    [2020-11-12 00:15:00, 2020-11-12 00:20:00, 202...
dtype: object
```

Then with `explode` we can make these into their own series. I’m using the series twice, once for the beginning of the interval and once for the end, so shifted. Note the `groupby().shift()` which allows to perform the shift only within the same index.

```
>>> interval_ends = pd.concat([bounds.explode(), bounds.explode().groupby(level=0).shift(-1)], axis='columns', keys=['start', 'end'])
>>> interval_ends
                start                 end
0 2020-11-11 22:15:00 2020-11-11 22:20:00
0 2020-11-11 22:20:00 2020-11-11 22:20:02
0 2020-11-11 22:20:02                 NaT
1 2020-11-11 23:10:00 2020-11-11 23:15:00
1 2020-11-11 23:15:00 2020-11-11 23:20:00
1 2020-11-11 23:20:00 2020-11-11 23:20:05
1 2020-11-11 23:20:05                 NaT
2 2020-11-12 00:15:00 2020-11-12 00:20:00
2 2020-11-12 00:20:00 2020-11-12 00:20:02
2 2020-11-12 00:20:02                 NaT
```

After that we can discard the indexes and simply compute the time inside each interval:

```
>>> interval_ends.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
>>> delays = (interval_ends['end'] - interval_ends['start']).astype('timedelta64[s]')
>>> delays
0    300.0
1      2.0
2      NaN
3    300.0
4    300.0
5      5.0
6      NaN
7    300.0
8      2.0
9      NaN
dtype: float64
```

Finally we just have to join the interval starts with these delays and drop lines containing `NaN`s, and we’ve got your final result:

```
>>> delays = delays.rename('time_in_secs').dropna().astype('int')
>>> interval_ends[['start']].join(delays, how='inner')
                start  time_in_secs
0 2020-11-11 22:15:00           300
1 2020-11-11 22:20:00             2
3 2020-11-11 23:10:00           300
4 2020-11-11 23:15:00           300
5 2020-11-11 23:20:00             5
7 2020-11-12 00:15:00           300
8 2020-11-12 00:20:00             2
```

Comment: since it is the time consumed feature, so date range should go back in time, not forward

Comment: @ManuSharma I’ve tweaked the `pd.date_range`, the rest is still the same. It now gives intervals going back in time (but still starting at multiples of 5 minutes).

Comment: Thank You so much, your answer really helped me :-)